# Rails pluralization and negative numbers

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```rb
irb(main):004:0> pluralize(1, "place")
=> "1 place"
irb(main):005:0> pluralize(-1, "place")
=> "-1 places" #Should be singular
```

Is this a bug, or some how intended?

In any case, how could I monkey patch this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was originally reported in the rails buglist until the core team decided to keep it as it after evaluating the pluralize method under different scenarios . Check out the thread below , it should give you an idea on why they did not update the pluralize to handle negative numbers

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/6533

There is a patch attached to this ticket which I think you can use to customize the pluralize method under the scope of your app